# Transferring socket to a map

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

I am trying to transfer a socket I just created in to a map-unsigned,SOCKET- but it look like it is not working. The reason i am trying to put in into a map is because I need to keep track of the client connections.
Here is where I accept a connection request:

```
SOCKET hAccepted = accept ( hSocket, NULL, NULL);
if(hAccepted == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
else
{
    unsigned clientId = 0;
    recv(hAccepted,reinterpret_cast<char *>( &clientId ), sizeof( clientId ),0);            

    if(clientSockets.find(clientId) == clientSockets.cend())
        clientSockets[clientId] = hAccepted;
    else 
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

My client is send a unique id right after it connect and I want my map to manage them after.

Comment: is this windows code?

Comment: Yes it is but for a console project